# Prevent users from disabling office add-ins?

Tags: office-js

I'm planning to write an JS office add-in which would depend on only administrators having rights to disable it.

For COM addins, i'm aware that you can either hide  the add-in from the UI by setting registry keys, how would I prevent standard users from disabling a JS add-in?

Comment: I truly hope that this is not possible, for security and troubleshooting purposes the user should always have the option to turn add-ins off. Think malicious code. Think buggy code. The user needs to be in control. Don't "force" people to use your add-in, educate them so they see why they should.

Comment: Office.js add-in have to be invoked by user in order to perform an operation. What is the reason do not allow to this user to disable (turn off) the add-in if anyway you would relay on this user action? Even if you would restrict the add-in from disabling by end user, this user may not invoke the add-in anyway.

Comment: @teylyn there are scenarios where corporate IT may want all users using a certain add in, e.g. if it helps with regulatory compliance in some way.

Comment: @teylyn - Igaud's description is exactly the scenario this use case is modelled on, where users must perform an action within a corporate environment as part of a compliance workflow (this specific scenario is for banking).

Comment: @AndrewO So, this is where my suggestion to educate the users comes in. If they don't understand why they should use the add-in or they refuse to use it, well, that would be a career-limiting move.

Answer (score 0):

I will encourage to learn and use the Centralized deployment feature for Office Add-ins. This is a tool that enable IT to deploy, update or remove add-ins within the Enterprise (as long as they have both Office 365/hybrid) targeting specific users or groups.

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Deploy-Office-Add-ins-in-the-Office-365-Admin-Center-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE

Disable on this context means explicitly removing the add-in from the user, btw.